# Getting dart import error in Flutter App upon upgrading

Tags: flutter, dart

I upgraded Flutter SDK for my perfectly working app today at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos for file - flutter_macos_3.3.6-stable.zip

However upon installing the folder, I am getting error at `dart:convert` which I use for Json conversions:

[image]

I did `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get` / `flutter get packages` and have restarted Android studio so many times. Rest all is working fine.

Am I missing something or dart:convert has been replaced with something else in the latest upgrade ?

**UPDATE (Solved)**

I reinstalled (unzipped) the file again & it stopped showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this one [here](https://pub.dev/packages/convert) , if that's not working